# POO no consigo enseñar listado en pantalla

Tags: javascript, array, poo, javascript-objeto

tengo  un array ya creada que se llama hotelList. De esta array quiero eliminar un hotel y pido al usuario que ponga el nombre. Entonces creo una funcion que se llama eliminateHOtel y ahi he picado este codigo. en consola me aparece solo el nuevo array creado por el metodo filter, pero no me aparece el nombre. ademas no se si el codigo esta bien. Me podeis ayudar? muchas gracias

```js
function eliminateHotel() {
  const userPrompt = prompt(
    "introduce el nombre del hotel que quieras eliminar"
  );
  let hotelEliminated = hotelList
    .filter(function (hotel) {
      return hotelList.name === userPrompt
```

Answer (score 1):

Para eliminar un objeto de un array puedes usar [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), que en su forma básica sería

```
let Elementos_eliminados = hotelList.splice(index_del_elemento,cantidad_de_elementos_a_eliminar);
```

```js
class Hotel{
  constructor(name){
    this.name=name;
  }
}
const hotelList=[];

function AddHotel(nombre){
  hotelList.push(new Hotel(nombre));
}

function GetHotelByName(nombre){
  return hotelList.find(h => h.name === nombre);
}

function GetHotelIndexByName(nombre){
  return hotelList.findIndex(h => h.name === nombre);
}

function RemoveHotelByName(nombre){
  return hotelList.splice(GetHotelIndexByName(nombre),1);
}
AddHotel("Hotel 1");
AddHotel("Hotel 2");
AddHotel("Hotel 3");

function eliminateHotel() {
  const userPrompt = prompt(
    "introduce el nombre del hotel que quieras eliminar"
  );
  if(userPrompt){
    let hotelEliminated = RemoveHotelByName(userPrompt);
  }
}
eliminateHotel();
console.log(hotelList);
```